# Parse/Iterate html file with Hpricot/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri, hpricot

I'm trying to parse an HTML file with the following format at the required section:

```
    <div style="something">
      <div class="link">
         <a href="http://..." class="headline">Headline</a>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
         Text summary is here
      </div>
      repeating...
   </div>
```

I want to output the headline followed by the text.

```
   HEADLINE
   Text goes here.

   HEADLINE
   Text goes here.
```

Currently I can search for the < a> tag with class="headline" and get a list and do the same with the text div. Then iterate through each to output the headline and text sequentially.

Can I get Hpricot/Nokogiri to save it in that order while it is parsing the file?

Comment: Does the text div always follow the headline div? Does the repeating part alternate between the two types of divs?

Comment: Yes. The text div follows the headline div and both repeat for every headline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//a[@class="headline"]').each do |headline|
  puts headline.text
  puts headline.xpath('../following-sibling::div[1]').text
end
```

Comment: I had managed to use this in Hpricot

 `(doc/"div[@class='link']").each do |a|
   puts a.search("//a[@class='headline']").inner_html
   puts a.next.inner_html
 end`
 
 but yours looks cleaner.